# Tree view with parent node automatically checks all its children

Tags: asp.net

I need a tree view with **parent node** automatically checks all its **children** in tree view.

I have

```
TreeView1.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All;
```

Can anyone help me..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this javascript, I got my requirement...

```
    function OnTreeClick(evt) {
        var src = window.event != window.undefined ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target;
        var isChkBoxClick = (src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input" && src.type == "checkbox");
        if (isChkBoxClick) {
            var parentTable = GetParentByTagName("table", src);
            var nxtSibling = parentTable.nextSibling;
            //check if nxt sibling is not null & is an element node
            if (nxtSibling && nxtSibling.nodeType == 1) {
                if (nxtSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") //if node has children
                {
                    //check or uncheck children at all levels
                    CheckUncheckChildren(parentTable.nextSibling, src.checked);
                }
            }
            //check or uncheck parents at all levels
            CheckUncheckParents(src, src.checked);
        }
    }

    function CheckUncheckChildren(childContainer, check) {
        var childChkBoxes = childContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var childChkBoxCount = childChkBoxes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < childChkBoxCount; i++) {
            childChkBoxes[i].checked = check;
        }
    }

    function CheckUncheckParents(srcChild, check) {
        var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", srcChild);
        var parentNodeTable = parentDiv.previousSibling;
        if (parentNodeTable) {
            var checkUncheckSwitch;
            if (check) //checkbox checked
            {
                var isAllSiblingsChecked = AreAllSiblingsChecked(srcChild);
                if (isAllSiblingsChecked)
                    checkUncheckSwitch = true;
                else
                    return; //do not need to check parent if any(one or more) child not checked
            }
            else //checkbox unchecked
            {
                checkUncheckSwitch = false;
            }

            var inpElemsInParentTable = parentNodeTable.getElementsByTagName("input");
            if (inpElemsInParentTable.length > 0) {
                var parentNodeChkBox = inpElemsInParentTable[0];
                parentNodeChkBox.checked = checkUncheckSwitch;
                //do the same recursively
                CheckUncheckParents(parentNodeChkBox, checkUncheckSwitch);
            }
        }
    }

    function AreAllSiblingsChecked(chkBox) {
        var parentDiv = GetParentByTagName("div", chkBox);
        var childCount = parentDiv.childNodes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            if (parentDiv.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
                //check if the child node is an element node
                if (parentDiv.childNodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "table") {
                    var prevChkBox = parentDiv.childNodes[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
                    //if any of sibling nodes are not checked, return false
                    if (!prevChkBox.checked) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //utility function to get the container of an element by tagname
    function GetParentByTagName(parentTagName, childElementObj) {
        var parent = childElementObj.parentNode;
        while (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() != parentTagName.toLowerCase()) {
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }
        return parent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("div[id=TrewView1] input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('table').next('div').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', this.checked);

            $(this).parents('div').each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checkbox').length > 0) {
                    $(this).prev('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode("Parent #" + i.ToString());
    node.Nodes.Add("Child #1");
    node.Nodes.Add("Child #2");
    node.Expand();

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
}

private void TreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
TreeView1.AfterCheck -= TreeView1_AfterCheck;

foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Nodes) {
    node.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
}

if (e.Node.Checked) {
    if (e.Node.Parent == null == false) {
        bool allChecked = true;

        foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.Nodes) {
            if (!node.Checked) {
                allChecked = false;
            }
        }

        if (allChecked) {
            e.Node.Parent.Checked = true;
        }

    }
} else {
    if (e.Node.Parent == null == false) {
        e.Node.Parent.Checked = false;
    }
}

TreeView1.AfterCheck += TreeView1_AfterCheck;
}
```

Comment: u can use this in asp